# Differential geometry and category theory

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, lie-groups

Does anyone know of a book/paper/anything, the longer the better introducing differential geometry from a category theoretic point of view? Everywhere it seems categorical language is the elephant in the room that isn't being addressed fully. I'm looking for something detailed, not just something that says the tangent bundle is a functor, but particularly the relationship between differential geometry constructs and laws in the categories they live in. An exposition on lie groups as well will be great.

My motivation for this is the haskell library manifolds http://hackage.haskell.org/package/manifolds, id like to understand the rational for the author's implementation but of I'd like some reference material

Comment: Maybe worth a look: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf Not clear to me exactly what you're looking for though. It's worth mentioning that, say, the category of smooth manifolds is somewhat poorly behaved as a category, e.g. it fails to have pullbacks.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't read this fully but it has been in my list for some time. This is what I want to understand, what category theoretic constructs map directly to differential geometric constructs on smooth manifolds? And do the laws from category theory for these constructions map directly to known theorems/lemas in differential geometry? I don't know if that makes sense?

Comment: What differential geometric constructs on smooth manifolds do you have in mind? Can you be more specific?

Comment: In particular, the tangent and cotangent bundle constructions, and connections

Comment: Oh and my motivation for this is the haskell library manifolds http://hackage.haskell.org/package/manifolds, id like to understand the rational for the author's implementation but of I'd like some reference material

Comment: Can you say what functionality is implemented in this Haskell library? What can it do with manifolds?

Comment: Try Synthetic Differential Geometry https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/synthetic+differential+geometry, or Tangent Categories https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tangent+category ; https://arxiv.org/search/?query=%22tangent+categories%22&searchtype=all&source=header

Comment: Lee's "Introduction to smooth manifolds" has a discussion about "smooth functors", which gives a nice categorical language to talk about the bundles constructed starting from the tangent bundle like the cotangent bundle, the tensor bundles,... see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_functor

Comment: @DeaneYang the package provides haskell types to represent manifolds in the most mathematically natural way without the usual compromise of discretisation. There are many constructs that are also implemented in an axiomatic way, charts, embeddings, bundles, etc

Comment: Can you give an example of what it can do with manifolds? Maybe a calculation or proof it can do? I’m still confused.

Comment: @DeaneYang If you have a look at the github page you will find a lot of examples of what the library can do. ODE/PDE solutions, computing gradients, sampling points in a space, parallel transport, and all of this computation begins with coordinate free definitions of the hypersurfaces he is working https://github.com/leftaroundabout/manifolds/tree/master/manifolds/images/examples. Also if you have time to explore, https://github.com/leftaroundabout/manifolds/tree/master/test you can find notebooks that show the code and the visualisations side by side.

Comment: @IsmailBello, thanks! I took a quick look but didn’t understand the pictures. I’ll take a closer look when I get a chance.